# Late 2011 MacBook Pro 13" stuck on white screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, memory, power, nvram

My Mac model is [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011) (MD314)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP645?locale=en_US).

Things I've tried so far:

- Reset NVRAM (PRAM) which actually does reset and laptop restarts when it resets.
- Reset SMC.
- Tried booting to Recovery, doesn't work, stuck on white screen.
- Tried booting to Internet Recovery, still stuck on white screen.
- Cleaned the contacts of the adapter charger and laptop's charging port with WD40 (dry contact cleaner for electronic equipments).
- Tried attaching an external monitor and external HDD.

I'm not sure what's wrong, it has upgraded RAMs (2*4 GB slots) and a Samsung Evo 250 GB SSD.

My laptop doesn't have a battery, when the charger is connected to the laptop, the light is always green when I'm stuck on the White Screen.

What should I do?

Comment: I can't afford a new laptop, any suggestion is appreciated <3

Comment: Stuck on a white screen is vague.  This happens at boot when the backlight and brightness  is turned on full during post. Do you get a logo when booting From any of the modes (safe, internet, etc.). If you do get a logo, try Verbose Mode (`Cmd-V` while booting).  Can you connect an  external monitor?

Comment: It looks like the graphics card has failed. But there's hope... if you start up your Mac in verbose mode (press and hold Command-V and turn your Mac on, release the keys after 15 sec, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573 for details), do you see text on the screen or still a white screen?

Comment: Hi Shayan, could you please check whether your screen displays text when starting up your Mac in verbose mode (press and hold Command-V and turn your Mac on, release the keys after 15 sec, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573 for details)?